# How do i pass a JavaScript variable to a PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, post

I'm working on a file where a table of products is extended using a counter variable in JavaScript. Now I need this counter variable in my PHP file so I know how many new products need to be written in the DB.If possible as as session variable.

Heres the JS code:

```
<!-- suspect code: -->
    <script>
        var counter = 0;
        function addproductrow() {
            var table = document.getElementById("product-table");
            var row = table.insertRow(0);
            var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
            var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
            cell1.innerHTML = `<button type="button" class="btn"><input type="text" name="product${counter}"></button>`;
            cell2.innerHTML = `<button type="button" class="btn"><input type="text" name="quantity${counter}"></button>`;
            counter++;
        }
    </script>
```

I need the table (form) to be submitted via post.

Any Ideas how I can do this?
PS. I cant use Jquery because this is a school project with plain JS.

Comment: You need to use ajax for this

Comment: Im not allowed to use Ajax but i added it to the question

Comment: If you not don't use ajax then need to form submit or something, normally you can not do this

Comment: I get the feeling that you think AJAX belongs to jQuery or some library/framework, it does  not. You can write AJAX with vanilla JS code quite happily, you always could. jQuery was used to smooth a few of the cross browser bumps out, those do not actually exist anymore if your using a modern browser

Comment: TL DR; [If you are interested](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX)

Answer (score 1):

You can't just pass variables between your backend and frontend they are running separately on different devices (one on the server the other on the client computer).

The most common way to communicate from client -> server is using asynchronous http requests (AJAX).
Have a look at the fetch API, it's built into pretty much every browser these days.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Answer (score 0):

There is a few ways but none are secured. Your way is probably one of the worst ^^

You can also have an hidden input and in your JS function :

```
document.getElementById('yourinputid').value = counter
```

and retrieve it with php. Some mad dev do that in their forms